# vector of std::promise throws exception but boost::promise does not

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, future

Question : What is the proper way to store a collection of promises given out ?

I am using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4 with "-std=c++11".  (update: upgraded to g++5.3 now, see comments)

The following code throws an exception when the promise.set_value() is called.  Message is "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'  what():  Unknown error -1 Aborted (core dumped)"

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    {   
        std::vector<std::promise<int>> q;
        std::promise<int> p;
        auto f = p.get_future();
        q.push_back(std::move(p));
        auto t1 = std::move(q.front());
        t1.set_value(10);
    }   
}
```

If I replace the std::promise with a boost::promise, it works

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

int main()
{
    {   
        std::vector<boost::promise<int>> q;
        boost::promise<int> p;
        auto f = p.get_future();
        q.push_back(std::move(p));
        auto t1 = std::move(q.front());
        t1.set_value(10);
    }   
}
```

What is most surprising is that the std::promise::set_value() does *not* throw an exception (or maybe gets caught somewhere?) if I just retain a declaration of the boost::promise in the program !

```
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

int main()
{
    {   // this hides the exception thrown by promise::set_value()
        boost::promise<int> p;
    }   

    {   
        std::vector<std::promise<int>> q;
        std::promise<int> p;
        auto f = p.get_future();
        q.push_back(std::move(p));
        auto t1 = std::move(q.front());
        t1.set_value(10);
    }   
}
```

Update:
Compilation options
 -Wextra -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 [yes, I added a proper definition of main and introduced (void) argc and (void) argv above]

ldd output

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe51fe000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa542df1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa542bda000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa542813000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa54250d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa54311f000)
```

Comment: Since you managed to compile with no return type for `main`, it may be possible to add options that increases the compiler's standards conformance and number of warnings.

Comment: Unable to reproduce with MinGW g++ 5.1 in Windows. Also unable to reproduce with Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: Also unable to reproduce with clang 7. Sounds like you just need to upgrade your compiler. GCC 4.8.4 is a year old, and we're already up to GCC 5.2.

Comment: Upgraded to g++5.3 and still seeing same error "g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) 5.3.0 20151204"

Comment: My compilation options : "g++ -Werror -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11"

Comment: Tried linking with "-lpthread" but its not used.  This is the "ldd" output of my executable on Ubuntu 14.04   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe51fe000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa542df1000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa542bda000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa542813000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa54250d000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa54311f000)

Comment: Seems fine under GCC 5.1 on ideone.com [here](http://ideone.com/S6JC8N).  Are you running the *exact* code you've posted, or some more elaborate code?

Comment: How about `-Wl,--no-as-needed -pthread` as per this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201)

Comment: @TonyD, yes running the exact same code.  Funny, maybe something is broken in my toolchain ?  Also tried -Wl,--no-as-needed but to no avail

Comment: File a bug report then.

Comment: GCC 5.2 on OSX, compiled with `g++ --std=c++11 foo.cpp`, works fine, as does clang 7. So you might not be compiling with the compiler you think you are.

Comment: One of my colleagues was able to reproduce the error on his laptop using Fedora with g++ 4.9.   This is *confusing*.  Going to try clang.  Does anyone know how I can isolate the line in future.h which is throwing the error

Comment: @SandeepJ I ran the example provided by the OP in gdb using gcc 4.8 and put the backtrace in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jacquelinekay/4790d2adda5d7e312e5d). The relevant line number in stdlib future is 358, though the error appears to be thrown from line 794 of mutex.

Comment: @Jackie thanks!   let me trace it further.   So you are able to reproduce the error as well ?